# How to use texture generated by TexturePacker in CocosBuilder?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

I know it's possible to create texture by Smart Sprite feature in CocosBuilder 3.0. But it's very unstable now. So I decided to use TexturePacker to generate the texture. My .plist and .png files are generated into different folders for different resolution inside my CocosBuilder project folder like this:

[image]

The problem is only the .png files shown in CocosBuilder (I can't find the .plist file):

[image]

Of course if I move the .png and .plist file into Resources folder. Both are will be shown inside CocosBuilder. But I have no way to select correct image for different resolution any more. I don't know what wrong with it. Any idea?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sovled the problem. Actually it's because the folder structure. The CocosBuilder doesn't recognize resources-iphone folder. So I rearranged the folder structure like this. Then everything is fine.

[image]